# Problem adding javascript/jquery to my WebPart

Tags: jquery, javascript

My ascx looks like this:

```
<SharePoint:ScriptLink ID="ScriptLink1" runat="server" Name="/_layouts/1033/MyProject/js/test.js"/>
test: <input id="example" />
```

test.js looks like this:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    alert("test");
});
```

In `MyProject` I have a folder called `js` and in that folder I have `test.js`

I was under the impression that when I debugged my webpart it would pop up an alert taht said "test" but it does nothing.  Am I doing something wrong here?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Do you have a reference to jquery on the page **before** the test.js include? Try using http://spc3.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=ClientScript&referringTitle=Home

Are there any script errors, is jquery loaded, try testing this before the alert:

```
if (typeof jQuery == 'undefined') {   
    alert('jQuery not loaded')   
}
```

Try adding this at the top of your include to make sure the include path is right

```
alert('test.js loaded')
```

Is it a VS2010 project? You need to add one of the sharepoint mapped folders, say LAYOUTS, and make your folder stucture under that (can't start with a folder called js)

```
MyProject/LAYOUTS/1033/MyProject/js/test.js
```

Comment: Sorry, I left the jQuery part out.  It is in my actual code, just didn't copy it over.  I have not added the `LAYOUTS` folder yet so that is probably the problem.  Is it just as simple as creating a folder called `LAYOUTS` or is there more to it?

Comment: For anyone interested in how to add Mapped Folders see this link:  http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee231521.aspx